# To Show/Hide <div> tag depending on the selection from previous drop down box

Tags: javascript

I have read many tutorials and many answers on stack overflow as well but it still does not work for me.Upon selecting an  option (Yes)from drop down -> it should show the `<div>` tag otherwise `<div>` should be hidden.

Below is my code:

```
<h4>1. Does your school participate in the sponsored CAT4 scoring initiative?</h4>
            @{
                List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Yes",
                    Value = "True"
                });
                listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "No",
                    Value = "False"
                });
            }
            <div class="form-group" id="PickOption">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParticipateInCAT4Scoring, listItems, "<----Select Yes or No---->", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParticipateInCAT4Scoring, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="OnYes" class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.Label("For what Grade levels?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GradeLevelsCAT4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GradeLevelsCAT4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>
```

Below is the Script file which I am placing at bottom of View page:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PickOption').on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 'True') {
                    document.getElementById('OnYes').style.display = "";
               

                }

                    else {
                    
                 document.getElementById('OnYes').style.display = "none";
                 
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not right, please make sure that you bind event on dropdown so add a class on dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParticipateInCAT4Scoring, listItems, "<----Select Yes or No---->", new { @class = "form-control pickerDropdown" })
```

Now bind the event on added class like this:

```
$('.pickerDropdown').on('change', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

`PickOption` is the ID of the wrapping div.

Replace `#PickOption` on this line with the ID or selector of the select box (usually auto-generated but you can specify.

```
            $('#PickOption').on('change', function () {
```

Also since you're using jQuery, you can just do `$('#OnYes').show();`

https://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PickOption').on('change', function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "False") {
                        $("#OnYes").show();
              
                }

                    else {
                    $("#OnYes").hide();
                    }
                });
            }); I have used this code but it only executes else part , is there something wrong with the value I am using here  in if statement?

Comment: div elements do not have a change event, select boxes do. Mateen provided an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71944577/18217648